# Хочу спарсить ссылки на клипы с помощью selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

```
def parse():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--mute-audio')
    options.add_argument("--incognito")
    options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
    browser.get("https://vk.com")
    browser.find_element_by_id('index_email').send_keys(username)
    browser.find_element_by_id('index_pass').send_keys(password)
    browser.find_element_by_id('index_login_button').click()
    time.sleep(2)

    browser.get('https://vk.com/clips/')
    time.sleep(30)

parse()
```

не могу понять, как мне это реализовать
Подскажите, как спарсить ссылки на клипы, с этой страницы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Вам лучше использовать `BeautifulSoup` для решения вашей задачи.

```
html=requests.get('url')
soup=BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
link=soup.find('a', class_="page_post...").get('href')
```

Если для парсинга требуется регистрация. то используйте `requests.Session` для сохранения coockie файлов